# Populate a combo box with a list of last 10 latest folders from a directory

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

I have a combo box that I want to be filled with a list of last 10 latest folders in a specified directory. Say,

There are 40 folders. In the combo box it should list the latest 10 folders.

Thank you,

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim name

  For Each name In ListDirectory(Path:="C:\Users\AllertonFC\Documents\FA Level 1 & Level 2\", AttrInclude:=vbDirectory, AttrExclude:=vbSystem Or vbHidden)
    Me.ComboBox1.AddItem name
  Next name
End Sub

Function ListDirectory(Path As String, AttrInclude As VbFileAttribute, Optional AttrExclude As VbFileAttribute = False) As Collection
  Dim Filename As String
  Dim Attribs As VbFileAttribute

  Set ListDirectory = New Collection

  ' first call to Dir() initializes the list
  Filename = Dir(Path, AttrInclude)

  While Filename <> ""
    Attribs = GetAttr(Path & Filename)
    ' to be added, a file must have the right set of attributes
    If Attribs And AttrInclude And Not (Attribs And AttrExclude) Then
      ListDirectory.Add Filename, Path & Filename
    End If
    ' fetch next filename
    Filename = Dir
  Wend
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, I find it easier to put values into a string and split it at the last minute into an array, also not using Dir, instead using a Scripting.FileSystemObject

```
Public Sub cBoxFiller()
   Dim oFS As Object, SrcFldr As String, oFldr As Object, xFldr As Object
   Dim FldrsTxt As String, FldrsAR() As String, GudCtr As Long
   Dim cBoxTxt As String, i As Long

   SrcFldr = "C:\Users\AllertonFC\Documents\FA Level 1 & Level 2\"
   Set oFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
   Set oFldr = oFS.getfolder(SrcFldr)

   ' Generate an Array of ALL SubFolders
     FldrsTxt = ""
     For Each xFldr In oFldr.subFolders
        FldrsTxt = IIf(FldrsTxt = "", "", FldrsTxt & vbCrLf) & xFldr.name  ' or xFldr.Path
     Next xFldr
     FldrsAR = Split(FldrsTxt, vbCrLf)
   ' Done

   ' Build a String of Last 10 Folders - separated by VbCrLf
     GudCtr = 0
     For i = UBound(FldrsAR) To LBound(FldrsAR) Step -1
        If GudCtr < 10 Then
           GudCtr = GudCtr + 1
           cBoxTxt = IIf(cBoxTxt = "", "", cBoxTxt & vbCrLf) & FldrsAR(i)
        End If
     Next i
   ' Done

   ' Split into an Array & Assign to the ComboBox
     ComboBox1.List = Split(cBoxTxt, vbCrLf)
   ' Done
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for this Tin, however what if I would like to list last 10 folders based on creation date.

Comment: Sorting is more complex - Look for a VBA Sort routine, you would also need a multi-dimensional array in place of FldrsAR and then sort that array before creating the array of 10

Comment: Thank You, I will give it a go much appreciated.